# How to query all users's posts in firebase collection that are saved under specific user?

Tags: firebase, flutter

This code queries posts for a specific user by its uid, however i want to query all posts from all users in one screen. Is it possible? Thanks for any help.

```
   StreamBuilder(
            stream: loadChallenges(context),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 210,
                  child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                          width: 40,
                          height: 40,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
                );
              return new ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      myCardDetails(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]));
            }),

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> loadChallenges(BuildContext context) async* {
    final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('userData')
        .document(uid)
        .collection('challenges')
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Comment: that's no possible as of the moment. You would have to somehow save the uid of the other user and reference the other user's database

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! Get the DocumentSnapshot.

`Firestore.instance.collection('userData').snapshots()` returns a stream of DocumentSnapshot.